# returning result from another nodejs file

Tags: node.js

i am working on a project in which a nodejs program calls another program in a separate file.

this is how i've added the two:

```
var ocr = require('./index.js'); //this imports the file
var arr = ocr.ocr_pan(); //this calls the function in that file
```

am not sure but I guess the problem is that the process resumes before ocr.ocr_pan() returns the result and var arr becomes undefined.

or there is some problem in returning the result from ocr.ocr_pan()

I simply use return.

and I have also tried this : [How to return array from module in NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29345607/3781320)

didn't work

what more can be done?

Comment: *"am not sure but I guess the problem is that the process resumes before ocr.ocr_pan() returns the result and var arr becomes undefined."* that makes no sense. If that's the case, then you're trying to return from an asynchronous callback and this has nothing to do with it being in a separate module. **Include the relevant parts of index.js in your question.**

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that this file is the same directory as `index.js` file, code in `index.js` should be something like this:

```
// Write your function
var ocr_pan = function() {
    // Do whatever you like
    return result;
};

// Export it, make publicly visible to other files
module.exports = {
    ocr_pan: ocr_pan
};
```